# Can not find suitable configuration of distributed configuration store when initializing Patroni as sudo

Tags: postgresql, high-availability, patroni

I followed the example described here https://www.opsdash.com/blog/postgres-getting-started-patroni.html and everything works as expected.

While testing, I tried `sudo patroni  pg-2.yml`. The output was:

```
2022-01-13 11:39:22,316 INFO: Failed to import patroni.dcs.consul
2022-01-13 11:39:22,316 INFO: Failed to import patroni.dcs.etcd
2022-01-13 11:39:22,317 INFO: Failed to import patroni.dcs.etcd3
2022-01-13 11:39:22,318 INFO: Failed to import patroni.dcs.exhibitor
2022-01-13 11:39:22,319 INFO: Failed to import patroni.dcs.raft
2022-01-13 11:39:22,319 INFO: Failed to import patroni.dcs.zookeeper
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/patroni", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/patroni/__init__.py", line 182, in main
    return patroni_main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/patroni/__init__.py", line 140, in patroni_main
    abstract_main(Patroni, schema)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/patroni/daemon.py", line 98, in abstract_main
    controller = cls(config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/patroni/__init__.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.dcs = get_dcs(self.config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/patroni/dcs/__init__.py", line 110, in get_dcs
    raise PatroniFatalException("""Can not find suitable configuration of distributed configuration store
patroni.exceptions.PatroniFatalException: 'Can not find suitable configuration of distributed configuration store\nAvailable implementations: kubernetes'
```

Is there an explanation for that?